# How does Ctrl-F render text highlights?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

AFAIK, programmatic text highlighting on a webpage is achieved by wrapping it in some sort of tag, then attaching some identifier to that tag and styling it. From what I can see in chrome devtools, Ctrl-F doesn't do this, allowing it to be much faster by avoiding the overhead of updating the DOM, it seems?

How is Ctrl-F rendering those highlights specifically?

Comment: It's a built-in feature of the browser so it's implemented internally.

Comment: Exactly, Chrome is rendering the DOM so it can render elements however it likes, independent of DOM elements or properties.

Comment: You don't need extra DOM elements to highlight whatever. You can highlight a range of text by using range. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse.